# Rotationally Invariant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

please, what it mean: $I_{\lambda}: W^{1,p}_0(\Omega_{\lambda})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is rotationally invariant

Where $I_{\lambda}(u)=\frac1p\int_{\Omega_{\lambda}}(|\nabla u|^p+|u|^p
) dx-\int_{\Omega_{\lambda}} F(u) dx$
and $\Omega_{\lambda}=\lambda\Omega$, $\lambda>0$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a smooth bounded domain.

How to see that a function is rotationally invariant
?